# Set pixel color to a sphere in OpenGL

Tags: opengl

I have used QUAD_STRIP to display squares with different colours and a mouse function to capture the color. The captured color should be set to a spehre. I can read color values but I'm unable to set  the read color values to the sphere.  Sphere is not displayed when given within mouse function. But shows up when given in display() function.

```
        #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <GL/gl.h>
    #include <GL/glu.h>
    #include <GL/glut.h>
    #include<windows.h>    
    float height=480,width=500;        
    GLUquadricObj *sphere = NULL;
    GLubyte *img;
    static void Init() {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
        glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
                    sphere = gluNewQuadric();
        gluQuadricDrawStyle(sphere, GLU_FILL);
        gluQuadricTexture(sphere, GL_TRUE);
        gluQuadricNormals(sphere, GLU_SMOOTH);

        glClearColor(1,1,1,0);

    }

    static void display() {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
   //glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // sets color to black.
          glBegin(GL_QUAD_STRIP);
    //1 q
            glColor3f(.5,0.5,1);
            glVertex2f(-1, 0.5 );
            glVertex2f(-1, 0.75 );
            glVertex2f(-0.75, 0.5 );
            glVertex2f(-0.75, 0.75 );
            // 2q
            glColor3f(.25,.5,0);

            glVertex2f(-0.5, 0.5 );
            glVertex2f(-0.5, 0.75 );

            //3q
            glColor3f(0.8,0.8,0.4);

            glVertex2f(-0.25, 0.5 );
            glVertex2f(-0.25, 0.75 );
            // 4th QUAD
            glColor3f(0.7,0.3,0.6);
            glVertex2f(0, 0.5);
            glVertex2f(0, 0.75 );

            // 5th QUAD
            glColor3f(0, 0.7,0.3);

            glVertex2f( 0.25, 0.5);
            glVertex2f(0.25,  0.75 );

    glEnd();

   glBegin(GL_QUAD_STRIP);
    //1 q
            glColor3f(.5,0.5,.5);
            glVertex2f(-1, 0.25 );
            glVertex2f(-1, 0.5 );
            glVertex2f(-0.75, 0.25 );
            glVertex2f(-0.75, 0.5 );
            // 2q
            glColor3f(.5,0.1,0.1);

            glVertex2f(-0.5, 0.25 );
            glVertex2f(-0.5, 0.5 );

            //3q
            glColor3f(0.1,0.1,0.4);

            glVertex2f(-0.25, 0.25 );
            glVertex2f(-0.25, 0.5 );
            // 4th QUAD
            glColor3f(1,1,0.5);
            glVertex2f(0, 0.25);
            glVertex2f(0, 0.5 );

            // 5th QUAD
            glColor3f(0.76, 0.3,0);

            glVertex2f( 0.25, 0.25);
            glVertex2f(0.25,  0.5 );

    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_QUAD_STRIP);
    //1 q
            glColor3f(.5,0,.5);
            glVertex2f(-1, 0 );
            glVertex2f(-1, 0.25 );
            glVertex2f(-0.75, 0 );
            glVertex2f(-0.75, 0.25 );
            // 2q
            glColor3f(.5,.3,0.3);

            glVertex2f(-0.5, 0 );
            glVertex2f(-0.5, 0.25 );

            //3q
            glColor3f(0.2,0.3,0);

            glVertex2f(-0.25, 0 );
            glVertex2f(-0.25, 0.25 );
            // 4th QUAD
            glColor3f(0,0,0);
            glVertex2f(0, 0);
            glVertex2f(0, 0.25 );

            // 5th QUAD
            glColor3f(1.0, 0,.5);

            glVertex2f( 0.25, 0);
            glVertex2f(0.25,  0.25 );

    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_QUAD_STRIP);
            glColor3f(1,0.5,0);
            glVertex2f(-1, -0.25 );
            glVertex2f(-1, 0.0 );
            glVertex2f(-0.75, -0.25 );
            glVertex2f(-0.75, 0.0 );

            glColor3f(1.0,1.0,0.0);

            glVertex2f(-0.5, -0.25 );
            glVertex2f(-0.5, 0.0 );


            glColor3f(0.0,0.0,1.0);

            glVertex2f(-0.25, -0.25 );
            glVertex2f(-0.25, 0.0 );
            // 2nd QUAD
            glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
            glVertex2f(-0.25, -0.25 );
            glVertex2f(-0.25, 0.0 );

            glVertex2f( 0, -0.25 );
            glVertex2f(0,  0.0 );

            // 3rd QUAD
            glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

            glVertex2f( 0.25, -0.25 );
            glVertex2f(0.25,  0.0 );

    glEnd();
glutSwapBuffers();

    }
    void moveBall(int key, int x, int y) {
    }
        void mouseMove(int x,int y) {
            y = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT ) - y;
            GLubyte pixel[3];
            float r,g,b;
            glReadPixels(x, y, 1, 1, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixel);
            r = pixel[0]/255.0;
            g = pixel[1]/255.0;
            b = pixel[2]/255.0;
            printf("red %f",r);
            printf("green %f",g);
            printf("blue %f",b);
            glColor3f(r,g,b);
            glTranslatef(0.75,0.25,0);
            gluSphere(sphere,0.1,20,20);
        }
    int main(int argc, char** argv) {

        glutInit(&argc,argv);
        glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH );
        glutInitWindowPosition( 10, 10);
        glutInitWindowSize(height,width);
        glutCreateWindow( "ColorBlocks");
        Init();
        glutDisplayFunc(display);
        glutSpecialFunc(moveBall);
        glutMotionFunc(mouseMove);
        glutMainLoop();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do is put the drawing of the sphere in the display and position it using the variables you get in mouseMove and have set to a global:

```
float sphereR,sphereG,sphereB;
void display(){
    //everything before the glutSwapBuffers(); call...

    glPushMatrix()
        glColor3f(r,g,b);
        glTranslatef(0.75,0.25,0);
        gluSphere(sphere,0.1,20,20);
    glPopMatrix()
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void mouseMove(int x,int y) {
    y = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT ) - y;
    GLubyte pixel[3];

    glReadPixels(x, y, 1, 1, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixel);
    sphereR = pixel[0]/255.0;
    sphereG = pixel[1]/255.0;
    sphereB = pixel[2]/255.0;
    printf("red %f",r);
    printf("green %f",g);
    printf("blue %f",b);

}
```

Comment: display() call is required in mouseMove() function right ?

Comment: @SmallStep no all information you need in display is stored in the `sphereR,sphereG,sphereB` variables and display will be called in its own pace by glut. you can ensure display will be called again by calling `glutPostRedisplay()` in mouseMove

Comment: Thank you. It works. But each time I select a color, the whole grid with sphere gets translated instead of just the sphere.

Comment: you can either translate it back or surround with push and pop matrix (or just step away from the old style openGL and manage your own transformations)